# PHP / jQuery - single quote doubled in Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, quotes

I hope this is not a duplicate, but all other problems with single quote in jQuery-Ajax-calls were talking about errors, not about what I observe here.

I have a Problem with jQuery-Ajax-calls which contain a single quote in the sent parameters - those are always doubled on the server side! I wrote a small playground-script, containing both front- and backend, to show the problem:

**playground.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["foo"])) { ?>
    <root>
        <fooVal>
            <?php echo $_REQUEST["foo"]; ?>
        </fooVal>
    </root>
    <?php 
    die;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function testSend() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "playground.php", 
                    data: {"foo" : $("#fooInput").val()},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#fooResult").text($(data).find("fooVal").text());
                    }
                });   
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="fooInput" />
        <a href="javascript:testSend()">send</a>
        <div id="fooResult"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I enter into the input field for example:

```
L'eclisse
```

The div#fooResult contains after the AJAX-call:

```
L''eclisse
```

So somehow the script made two single quotes out of one. Examining with firebug, I see that the Parameter is sent correctly with only one single quote. But the answer always contains two of them, no matter if I output (in the PHP part on the top of the script) in XML or via json_encode or just a plain echo.

**What I already tried:**

- using `encodeURI(($"#fooInput").val())` - no change
- using `encodeURIComponent(($"#fooInput").val())` - no change
- using `escape($("#fooInput").val())` - this will output L%27eclisse

Does anyone have a suggestion, what I might do? Either on the client (javascript) side or on the server (php) side of the script? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `L\'eclisse` from the client to see what comes back? To achieve that you'll need to escape it something like this `var string = $("#fooInput").val().replace(/'/g, "\\'");`

Comment: @FDL , tried it now, the result is: `\''eclisse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good Idea when building xml document to use an xml library to ensure you everything is being encoded correctly.

```
$doc = new DomDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$foo = $doc->createElement("fooVal", $_REQUEST["foo"]);
$root = $doc->createElement("root");
$root->appendChild($foo);
$doc->appendChild($root);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

**UPDATE:** Final Issue was magic_quotes where enabled. Resolution was to use a userland script to undo the escaping done by the setting since the user did not have access to change the configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, I'll keep that in mind!
Unfortunately, the problem persists... :/

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue with the above code. One thing that could be tripping you up is the php magic_quotes settings. see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) for more information.

Comment: That page helped me a lot, thank you!
Since unfortunately I can't access the php.ini, nor does the htaccess-solution there work, I had to use the solution under Example #2 (described as very inefficient...)

So it works, thanks!

Comment: Solution (at least for me) in 2nd comment to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just copy/pasted your code and it works just fine.

I think you should check your PHP.ini settings and have a look at magic_quotes.

in particular:

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
; http://php.net/magic-quotes-sybase
magic_quotes_sybase = On

Comment: This appears to probably be the most likely cause.

Comment: Thanks for that input!
Unfortinately, I don't have access to the php.ini :/ but using phpinfo() I found the following:

magic_quotes_gpc On On
magic_quotes_runtime Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase On On

So magic_quotes_sybase seems to be on...

Comment: perhaps you could try the solution listed in example #2 here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: @Elpy yup that's exactly what helped me out see below, Orangepill directed me to the same page, but thanks anyway!

Uhm.. I'm new here, is there any way to mark this question as solved?